# Can I instantiate a movieclip with new in Flash like in other labguages or am I obliged to load at runtime?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Instead of

```
public class MyMainMovieClip extends MovieClip {                          

  public function MySliderComponent() { 

    var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();     
    myLoader.load(new URLRequest("MySWF.swf"));
    myZone.addChild(myLoader);
    myZone.addChild(c);

  }
```

Can I instantiate as usual:

```
public class MyMainMovieClip extends MovieClip {                          

    public var c:MySWF = new MySWF();

  public function MySliderComponent() { 

    c.visible = true;
    myZone.addChild(c);

  }
```

I get no error in second case but nothing shows up but stays blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new instances of movieclip from a document class, but there's no way for flash to know what FLA the class belongs to, this is why you get no errors, but see nothing..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! Let's consider two cases.

### Same SWF

If you are compiling with Flash and the movieclip is in the library. You first have to set a "linkage name" for it. This will be the name of the class identifying this particular movieclip. Then to instantiate it:

```
var clipClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("linkageName") as Class;
var myClip:MovieClip = new clipClass() as MovieClip;
addChild(myClip);
```

A faster version of it (but less strict)

```
var myClip:MovieClip = new linkageName() as MovieClip;
addChild(myClip);
```

### Different SWF

If you are compiling with Flash, all you can do is loading the swf with a `Loader`, the two libraries will then be merged and you can use the same code as above.

If you are compiling with Flex SDK you can actually embed a specific movieclip in the SWF from an external library.

1. Create a movieclip in Flash
2. Give it a linkage name
3. Compile it to an swf or an swc
4. Write the following code in your AS code (compiled with Flex SDK)

AS3

```
[Embed(source='../bin/library.swf', symbol='linkageName')]
private const clipClass:Class;
...
var myClip:MovieClip = new clipClass() as MovieClip;
addChild(myClip);
```

Note that I have used the class `MovieClip` everywhere but they have only one frame you may use `Sprite` instead.

Comment: So basically the answer is, no you can't.. unless you use the same SWF or can use flex

Comment: `[Embed]` is not really Flex. You draw in a few Flex classes when you use it, but you can use it in a pure AS3 project. It's incredibly useful

Comment: Hmm you don't seem to agree :) As I understand if I put in library yes, if I don't put in library I can't ?

Comment: If you load the external swf, the libraries will be merged as I wrote. Then if your clip is in the library with a linkage name, you will be able to instantiate it.

And I'm not talking about Flex (the MXML framework) but Flex SDK (the compiler used by FlashBuilder and FlashDevelop...).